# How do I pass a JSON object to inline javascript In EJS

Tags: javascript, json, ejs

I just want to send EJS object to javascript function. I have tried below code but it didn't work.

```
<% books.forEach(function(book){ %>
    <button onclick="getBookDetails(<%=book %>);" > <%=book.name %></button>
  <% }); %>
```

My JavaScript code is

```
function getBookDetails(book){
   //using book object
}
```

I have tried following  stuff also.But it didn't help.`getBookDetails(<%=JSON.stringify(book) %>);`

Please help me to find the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call `getBookDetails(<%=book%>)` because `<%=book%>` will get evaluated as `[object Object]` and not `{ name: "Wind in the willows, author: "Kenneth Grahame" }` as you require.

You're on the right lines with using `JSON.stringify` but missed one crucial point: using `<%=` will escape html entities. Instead - use `<%-` like so:

```
<% books.forEach(function(book){ %>
    <button onclick="getBookDetails(<%-JSON.stringify(book)%>);"><%=book.name %></button>
<% }); %>
```

You're fine using `<%=book.name%>` because that should output a string.

Comment: You should wrap it with quotes: `onclick="getBookDetails('<%-JSON.stringify(book)'%>)`

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap your ejs 'stringified' value with single quotes, like this **'**<%= JSON.stringify(book) %>**'**:

```
<% books.forEach(function(book){ %>
    <button onclick="getBookDetails('<%= JSON.stringify(book) %>')"><%= book.name %></button>
<% }) %>
```

And inside the JS function, parse it firstly:

```
function getBookDetails(bookString){
   let book = JSON.parse(bookString)
   // now you can use the book object
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `JSON.parse().console.log(bookString)`.
It worked for me.